# Difference between Codec and MessageConverter in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

[Codec](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/whats-new.html#x4.2-codec)'s were introduced in Spring Integration 4.2.

However, the description in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#codec) doesn't really describe how a Codec is different from a [`MessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/converter/MessageConverter.html?is-external=true) or in which scenarios to use which abstraction?

Basically what I want to know is:

- Why was the `Codec` abstraction introduced when it seems similar to what a `MessageConverter` does?
- Why would you use a `Codec` over a `MessageConverter` and vice versa?
- When would you choose to use one over the other?

This question was highlighted in the context of [Spring Cloud Stream](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/tree/master/spring-cloud-stream-codec) where there is a default [Kryo Codec](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-codec/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/codec/kryo/KryoCodecAutoConfiguration.java) configured but recently there has been work [around `MessageConverter`'s](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/a7f21b542a6679b961f427d37e67e9d730ce8c88/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binding/MessageConverterConfigurer.java#L77).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of a grey area.

`MessageConverters` are used in Spring Integration in two areas:

1. To convert some external representation of a message to a spring-messaging `Message<?>` - e.g. to/from an mqtt message.
2. To implement the [datatype on message channels](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-datatype-channel).

Codecs, on the other hand only deal with message payloads when putting them on the wire (`MessageBus` in XD or `Binder` in Spring Cloud Stream). Kryo is an alternative to Java serialization.

Applications will typically not deal with Codecs directly, but Spring Integration provides a `CodecMessageConverter` which takes a codec to encode/decode the payload while converting.

It also provides a codec-based transformer so an app can do the encoding/decoding (if it wishes) somewhere else in the flow.

So, in the context of Spring Cloud Stream, the Kryo Codec is used to encode/decode the payload within the Binder.

The message converters are used to implement conversion within the application bound to the transport by the Binder, using the channel `dataType` feature.

Let's look at an example using Spring Cloud DataFlow:

```
stream create foo --definition "source | processor --outputType=application/json | sink"
```

Let's say the source emits some POJO that is received by the processor, and the processor internally normally emits a `Map` object, but the sink wants to receive JSON, then a `MessageConverter` does that for you because of the `outputType` declaration.

The data between source and processor, and processor and sink, are transported as kryo.

Comment: Given your example, would it be accurate to say: Given a simple POJO and a content type of `application/json` on the output channel, the POJO will be converted to JSON representation as `java.lang.String` (using `PojoToJsonMessageConverter` for example) and the "on the wire" payload would be `byte[]`, encoded with a Codec (in this case Kryo but could be Java serialisation). I.e. `MessageConverter`s convert to/from application/domain objects, while Codecs serialize at a lower level, i.e. what is sent over the actual binders.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Your stream definition uses `--outputType=application/json`, however this commit (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/pull/434/files#diff-ada8828737483d5cc8b1cfd04c00239cR168) mentions `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.contentType`. Assuming they (`outputType` vs. `contentType`) mean the same thing, Why are they named differently?

Comment: Because a processor has both input and output channels... `... | processor --inputType=foo outputType=bar | ...`. Remember, this example is in the context of spring-cloud-dataflow, not the underlying spring-cloud-stream.

Comment: @GaryRussell , I need to add a new kryo serializer ( I know how to create one), the standard kryo is not serializing correctly a Set<String> , I have been looking through the code, your name is all over it :-) good job and thanks! I was hopping you could shed some light as of how to tell spring integration about my new serializer? Do I need to create a new "Registrar" to handle new serializers? Just extend "Codec" and make it available as a bean?

Comment: I am done for the day. It's generally better to ask a new question rather than commenting on an old one. The answer mught depend on the context in which you are using the codec. So provide more context on a new question.

Comment: You are right, here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424269/spring-cloud-dataflow-register-new-custom-kryo-serializer I am also done for the day, if you have time tomorrow? or forward to somebody else...if you are busy? thanks!