# Spring Cloud dataflow: Register new custom kryo serializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am creating a system using cloud-dataflow, I have a source and a transformer. We like to use kryo, but some of our classes require custom kryo serializers, I have written serializers before. We are now using spring-integration-core-4.3.11, and since 4.2 the model has changes(per the docs) to use Codecs instead of MessageConverter interface.

The question is, how can I register the kryo serializers in the new Codec framework, do I make a new Codec implementation inheriting from MessageCodec? Do I create a new Registrar implementation?

Just making the implementation a bean would it be discovered? I found Codec being Autowired, but nowhere found them being produced....

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [KryoCodecAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/1.3.x/spring-cloud-stream-codec/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/codec/kryo/KryoCodecAutoConfiguration.java#L53).

You can either replace the standard `PojoCodec` with your own bean, or simply add your registrar (and any others needed) and SCSt will wire them into the default `PojoCodec`....

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(PojoCodec.class)
public PojoCodec codec() {
    Map<String, KryoRegistrar> kryoRegistrarMap = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(KryoRegistrar.class);
    return new PojoCodec(new ArrayList<>(kryoRegistrarMap.values()), kryoCodecProperties.isReferences());
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(KryoRegistrar.class)
public KryoRegistrar fileRegistrar() {
    return new FileKryoRegistrar();
}
```

Comment: that was perfect, thanks! my problems continue, but this one seems solved...thanks again!